# Creation of domain objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm creating an application with employee and employer as a domain objects. 
Both of them have a reference to User object where I store password and other account related stuff.

Example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    ...
    //other properties
}

public class Employer
{
    public Guid EmployerId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyDescription { get; set; }
    public string FoundedYear { get; set; }
    ...
    //other properties
}

public class User
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    ...
   //other properties
}
```

I'm also using application services where a method represents a single use case.
Let's say I have RegisterEmpolyee method that should save employee to database set his role to "Employee" and send verification email.

This is my code right now. I'm using AspNet.Core.Idenity.UserManager to create user account:

```
    public async Task<EmployeeDto> RegisterEmployee(RegisterEmployeeDto employee)
    {
        var validateResult = _validatorService.Validate(employee);
        if (!validateResult.IsValid)
            throw new ServerException
                ("RegisterEmployeeDto is not valid", validateResult.GetErrors());

        await _db.BeginTransactionAsync();
        var newUser = new User { UserName = employee.Email, Email = employee.Email };
        var userCreationResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, employee.Password);

        if (!userCreationResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userCreationErrors = userCreationResult.GetIdentityResultErrors();
            throw new ServerException("Error during create User account.", userCreationErrors);
        }

        await _roleService.AddUserToRoleAsync(newUser.Id, ApplicationRoles.Employee);
        var verificationCode = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser);
        newUser.VerificationCode = verificationCode;

        await _emailService.SendActivationEmail(newUser.Email, newUser.Id, verificationCode);

        var newEmployee = new Employee(employee.Name, employee.Surname, newUser);

        await _db.Employees.AddAsync(newEmployee);
        await _db.CompleteAsync();

        var employeeDto = _mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeDto>(newEmployee);

        _db.CommitTransaction();

        return employeeDto;
    }
```

And here are my questions:

1. Does this code and my approach are fine according to DDD?
2. Should I extract creation of employee to domain service? Or maybe factory? And if so should I call repository method from there? (I mean service of course)
3. Let's say should extract creation of employee to domain service. Should I create User internally then?

Like this:

```
    public async Task<Employee> CreateEmployee(RegisterEmployeeDto employee)
    {
        var newUser = new User { UserName = employee.Email, Email = employee.Email };
        var userCreationResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, employee.Password);

        if (!userCreationResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var userCreationErrors = userCreationResult.GetIdentityResultErrors();
            throw new ServerException("Error during create User account.", userCreationErrors);
        }

        var newEmployee = new Employee(employee.Name, employee.Surname, newUser);
        //Should I call repository here? 
        await _db.Employees.AddAsync(newEmployee);
        await _db.CompleteAsync();

        return newEmployee;
    }
```

Or maybe pass User as a parameter?

4. And last question: Where is a right place to checking if user I want to create exist or not? Is Application service appropriate place to do so?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: I would argue that the entity design is wrong in the first place. `Employee` and `Employer` both should inherit from `User`, rather than using composition. In other words, an `Employee` is a `User`, rather than `Employee` has a `User`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for reply. I considered to use inherit but I've read many times that composition should be used over inheritance. Anyway how would I deal with database if i did so? Would I have one table for Employees and Employers and some empty fields? Honestly I don't know how entity framework handle this. Could you explain?

Comment: Not sure where you read that, but it's not the case. Composition should be used when it makes sense. For example a `Car` has an `Engine`; it is not an `Engine` itself. The one exception is with multiple inheritance. When a thing is in fact multiple different things, you have to use composition, simply because C# doesn't support multiple inheritance. However, when there's a direct line of descendance, use inheritance.

Comment: As far as the database goes, there's different strategies you can employ. Which is largely dependent on personal preference and the individual needs of the application. The default is STI (single table inheritance), where all the fields from all derived types go in the same table and a "discriminator" column is added so EF can instantiate the right type. However, you can also choose TPT (table per type), which will give each entity its own table and use joins to materialize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, `User`, `Employee` and `Employer` are Aggregate roots (AR).

> Does this code and my approach are fine according to DDD?

In DDD it's not recommended that an Aggregate have references to other Aggregates other than [by ID](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_1.pdf). Your `Employee` and `Employer` AR have such a *bad* reference so it is not OK. Instead `Employee` and `Employer` should contain only a `UserId` field.

> Should I extract creation of employee to domain service? Or maybe factory? And if so should I call repository method from there? (I mean service of course)

From what I can see you have a complex process of creating multiple Aggregates. In DDD you cannot do this atomically, inside a single transaction. Instead, every Aggregate is created/mutated in its own transaction. There is however a tactical pattern of coordinating a long process: Saga/Process manager.

You should define a process of registering an employee as a Saga: `RegisterEmployee`. This process should have an interface with these methods: `create`, `start`, `continue`. The `create` method receive all the data it needs to start process. The `start` method tries to run the individual steps (like createEmployee, createUser etc); if the `start` method is run again, it should continue from where has stopped, so the Saga should record its status.

The architecture can be made better by making the command on Aggregates as idempotent. In this way, when a Saga restarts it can send again all the commands to the Aggregates; this effectively makes the Saga very simple.

> Let's say should extract creation of employee to domain service. Should I create User internally then?

That domain service is in fact the Saga from the previous step. The Saga however should not contain logic that belongs to the Aggregates! Be carefully to not make your domain model anaemic. The Saga should contain only coordinating logic!

> And last question: Where is a right place to checking if user I want to create exist or not? Is Application service appropriate place to do so?

What means that an User already exists? There is already an user with that username? If yes, then the simplest solution is to have an unique index on the `username` column, if possible. If it's not possible (i.e. you have sharding enabled) then you can have another Saga that checks for duplicates and reports to an Admin or something.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does Saga/Process manager is necessary or it is also fine to simple use factory? I'm new with DDD and I've never heard about Saga. But I'm gonna read about it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @tabs0n it is necesarry: what happens if your app crashes in the middle of the process?